# Draw javascript image from PNG data

Tags: php, jquery, html, png

This may be a stupid question, but I'm not very familiar with images yet.

I have a PHP script that draws a PNG image.  The last two lines are

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

I want to call this with AJAX and then display it dynamically.  The problem is, when I get the data, it outputs a long string of letters, numbers, and symbols instead of an image.  I'm just putting in a div, which feels really naive.  How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to output image to temporary file, then display it:

```
<?php
   imagepng ($im, $filename);
?>
```

So "header" instruction set the type of content which displayed in browser directly.